# Dynamic member lookup with multiple keypaths for enums with associated values

Tags: ios, swift, enums, protocols, keypaths

Implementing dynamic member lookup on an enum with associated values leads to build errors when there is more than one keypath function.

I have an enum with multiple associates values, as described below:

```
@dynamicMemberLookup
enum Media {
    case movie(Movie)
    case book(Book)
    
    subscript<T>(dynamicMember keyPath: KeyPath<Entertainment, T>) -> T {
        switch self {
            case .movie(let movie):
                return movie[keyPath: keyPath]
            case .book(let book):
                return book[keyPath: keyPath]
        }
    }
}
```

The structs `Movie` and `Book` inherit protocols `Filmed` and `Written`, which themselves inherit from the more generic protocol `Entertainment`:

```
protocol Entertainment {
    var isbn: Int { get }
    var title: String { get }
    var sales: Int { get set }
}

protocol Written: Entertainment {
    var author: String { get }
}

protocol Filmed: Entertainment {
    var actors: [String] { get set }
}

struct Movie: Filmed {
    var isbn: Int
    var title: String
    var sales: Int
    var actors: [String]
}

struct Book: Written {
    var isbn: Int
    var title: String
    var sales: Int
    var author: String
}
```

So far, this works and has allowed me to access variables such as `isbn` and `title`, which are defined in `Entertainment`, from the top-level `Media` object through the subscript keypath lookup.

```
let media: Media = .movie(Movie(isbn: 1011, title: "Top Gun", sales: 1000, actors: ["Tom Cruise", "Miles Teller"]))

print(media.title)
print(media.sales)
```

Now, when I try to add the subscript function below in `Media` so that I can optionally access variables conforming to either `Filmed` or `Written`, I receive an error for the above print statements stating `Ambiguous use of 'subscript(dynamicMember:)'`

```
subscript<T>(dynamicMember keyPath: KeyPath<Filmed, T>) -> T? {
    switch self {
        case .movie(let movie):
            return movie[keyPath: keyPath]
        default:
            return nil
    }
}
```

In this example, the build errors are as follows:

```
let media: Media = .movie(Movie(isbn: 1011, title: "Top Gun", sales: 1000, actors: ["Tom Cruise", "Miles Teller"]))

print(media.title) // BUILD ERROR: Ambiguous use of 'subscript(dynamicMember:)'
print(media.sales) // BUILD ERROR: Ambiguous use of 'subscript(dynamicMember:)'
print(media.actors) // This doesn't throw an error and successfully logs
```

When I remove the second subscript function, the build errors are gone.

Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong in my implementation here.

Comment: What if you add a generic where condition to the subscript? It would look like this: subscript<T>(dynamicMember keyPath: KeyPath<Filmed, T>) -> T? where T: Media { .. }

Comment: I tried that but it threw the following build error: Type 'T' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'Media'

Comment: true, try constraining it to Entertainment instead?

Comment: That removes the build error in the subscript function, but now when I try and print(media.actors), I get the following error: Subscript 'subscript(dynamicMember:)' requires that '[String]' conform to 'Entertainment'.

Comment: That makes sense because of: 
    protocol Filmed: Entertainment {
         var actors: [String] { get set }
    }
How are you expecting this subscript on Entertainment to work?

Comment: The subscript function on Entertainment allows me to access attributes such as media.title without having to switch and parse each case in the Media enum. This is useful for all Entertainment object, however I would like to be able to do the same for objects which conform to Filmed. i.e. I could do media.actors to get the list of actors (given that media was of type .movie. if it was of type .book, it would return nil)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out the answer:

By changing `Filmed` and `Written` to no longer conform to `Entertainment`, the build errors were removed. The code as following now works:

```
protocol Entertainment {
    var isbn: Int { get }
    var title: String { get }
    var sales: Int { get set }
}

protocol Written {
    var author: String { get }
}

protocol Filmed {
    var actors: [String] { get set }
}

struct Movie: Entertainment, Filmed {
    var isbn: Int
    var title: String
    var sales: Int
    var actors: [String]
}

struct Book: Entertainment, Written {
    var isbn: Int
    var title: String
    var sales: Int
    var author: String
}

@dynamicMemberLookup
enum Media {
    case movie(Movie)
    case book(Book)
    
    subscript<T>(dynamicMember keyPath: KeyPath<Entertainment, T>) -> T {
        switch self {
            case .movie(let movie):
                return movie[keyPath: keyPath]
            case .book(let book):
                return book[keyPath: keyPath]
        }
    }

    subscript<T>(dynamicMember keyPath: KeyPath<Filmed, T>) -> T? {
        switch self {
            case .movie(let movie):
                return movie[keyPath: keyPath]
            default:
                return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output of the print statements:

```
let media: Media = .movie(Movie(isbn: 1011, title: "Top Gun", sales: 1000, actors: ["Tom Cruise", "Miles Teller"]))

print(media.title) // OUTPUT: "Tom Cruise"
print(media.sales) // OUTPUT: 1000
print(media.actors) // OUTPUT: Optional<[String]>: ["Tom Cruise", "Miles Teller"]
```